# Implementing CI/CD with Docker while mean application is in single repository in bitbucket

Tags: git, docker, bitbucket

I have a mean application running on bitbucket and all client and server folders are in single repository. Now I want to implement CI/CD pipelines with it. The problem is because of the client and server are in single repository. I will use docker-compose for building the docker image where one container will be of mean application and other one will be the database. I have implemented a `Dockerfile` for the same but it is not running as expected.

The thing is I will run client and servers on different ports but it is not working.

the folder structure of the app is as below.

```
mean-app
 - client
  - package.json
 - server
  - package.json
 - Dockerfile
 - docker-compose.yml
 - bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10 AS client

# copy the package.json to install dependencies
COPY client/package.json ./

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
# Install the dependencies and make the folder
RUN npm install && mkdir /usr/src/app/app-ui 

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/app-ui

COPY client/. .

# Build the project and copy the files
RUN npm run ng build -- --prod

FROM nginx:alpine

#!/bin/sh

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy from the stahg 1
COPY --from=client /usr/src/app/app-ui/dist/client /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 4200 80

# Create image based on the official Node 6 image from the dockerhub
FROM node:10

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/server

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/server

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY server/package.json /usr/src/app/server

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY server/. /usr/src/app/server

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 3000

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  mean: #name of the second service
    build: . # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app-ui
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "4200:4200"
      - "3000:3000" #specify ports forewarding
    links:
      - database

  database: # name of the third service
    image: mongo # specify image to build container from
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" # specify port forewarding
```

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        services:
          - docker
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          # Set $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME and $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD as environment variables in repository settings
          - export IMAGE_NAME=vm8198/mean

          # build the Docker image (this will use the Dockerfile in the root of the repo)
          - docker build -t vm8198/mean .
          # authenticate with the Docker Hub registry
          - docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
          # push the new Docker image to the Docker registry
          - docker push vm8198/mean:latest
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
```

Comment: why do you enclose port values into double quotes?

Comment: @mangusta I have tried without double quotes also but it is not working

Comment: Do you need a separate `client/Dockerfile` and `server/Dockerfile`?  In what way is it not working; do you get an error message you can add to the question?

Comment: @DavidMaze No need of dockerfile in client and server folder as build is done from root folder